# How do I make my shears be able to break iron bars in adventure mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a prison break minecraft map!
One of the items to help escape are shears, to let them break bars. I know the command to let blocks break other blocks in adventure mode, the default is adventure mode, and the only mistake showing up is the iron bars!
Here is my command:
/give @p shears 1 0 {CanDestroy: [iron_bars]}

Comment: why do questions like this always get downvoted at least once?

Comment: @BlazingTrio Mutliple reasons, but the main one for this one I think is that it could be answered with a quick google.

Answer (score 1):

The correct command is:

```
/give @p shears{CanDestroy:["minecraft:iron_bars"]}
```

In comparison your command was:

```
/give @p shears 1 0 {CanDestroy: [iron_bars]}
```

You may have been using a command for an older version of minecraft but eithere way the format is:

```
/give selector item{CanDestroy:["minecraft:block/item"]}
```

Don't forget to add the quotation marks.

Comment: Thank you, I really didn't see the quotation marks at first, so I just thought you took out the numbers! Thank you for editing!